# How to detect that two Office365 users work in the same organization via the API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

In my application, the user signs in using their Office365 credentials and then
I want to import the data of the users (`id`, `mail`, `displayName`) in the same 
organization into my database.

When another person from the same organization logs in into my app, that other
person should see the same list of users as the first one.

I tried several queries in the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/graph/graph-explorer#), but none 
of them has a response, which would allow to determine that two people belong
to the same organization.

"My profile" (`/v1.0/me/`) response contains a lot
of data, but no tenant ID (or something similar):

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
    "id": "16f5a7b6-5a15-4568-aa5a-31bb117e9967",
    "businessPhones": [],
    "displayName": "Anne Weiler",
    "givenName": "Anne",
    "jobTitle": "Manufacturing Lead",
    "mail": "annew@CIE493742.onmicrosoft.com",
    "mobilePhone": "+1 3528700812",
    "officeLocation": null,
    "preferredLanguage": "en-US",
    "surname": "Weiler",
    "userPrincipalName": "annew@CIE493742.onmicrosoft.com"
}
```

Same applies to the "all users in the organization" (`/v1.0/users`) response.

How can I extract the information from Microsoft Graph that would allow me to
detect that two different users work in the same organization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `id` returned by the [/organiozation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/organization) endpoint:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization?$select=id,displayName`

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#organization(id,displayName)",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "c07ab59f-ce09-49f8-b4c4-9c6dd4f0d8bb",
            "displayName": "Microsoft API Sandbox"
        }
    ]
}
```